# What percent of the population has some form of synesthesia?

Tags: neuroscience, sensation, epidemiology, synesthesia

Data I am trying to get my hands on:

- What types of [synesthesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia) (e.g. [Grapheme-color synesthesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme%E2%80%93color_synesthesia),  [Chromesthesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromesthesia), etc.) are most common across the population?
- What percent of population has that type of synesthesia?

It would also be great if there's geographical (genealogical) data on what types of synesthesia are more common to what areas.

**What percent of the population has what type of synesthesia?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The phenomenon**

Synesthesia is a neurological phenomenon in which a stimulus in one sensory or cognitive pathway triggers an experience in another.  Some hallmarks:<sup>1</sup>

- It tends to be developmental, arising early in childhood.
- It is involuntary.
- It is stable over time (i.e. the same stimulus leads to the same sensory experience).

**Epidemiology**

The best paper I found on the issue is by [Simner et al, 2006](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17076063).<sup>2</sup> The authors first review prior literature on the topic and then describe their own methodology and study addressing the question of prevalence. Regarding prior research:

> Estimates of the prevalence of synesthesia have diverged widely....estimates range from 1 in 4.....to 1 in 25000 - 100 000.

Not so helpful.

They point out some problems with prior studies: one group of surveys relied on self-referral and made the (conservative) assumption that all non-responders to an invitation to participate were non-synesthetes. Another set of studies avoided this problem by questioning every member of a participant pool but established the prevalence only “subjectively” (their wording, although I note that this is an inherently subjective phenomenon!).

Simner's own group used a validated survey questionnaire about specific synesthetic experiences (the specificity and prior validation of this overcoming the  "subjective" aspect in their view). They found an overall prevalence of 4.4% for any type of synesthesia. Importantly, the male: female ratio was not significantly different from 1 in this group, in contrast to many prior studies which have found a marked female predominance, ranging from 2:1 to 5:1 (references in Simner's paper for those interested).

**Modalities of experience**

To address your question about the types of sensory experience involved, I turn to a [more recent review article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=22428428)<sup>1</sup> that compiled results from multiple studies. In this report, grapheme-color type synesthesia was most common (86%). These participants see a number or letter and experience a particular color in association. This was followed by followed by time-space type (62%), a group who associates units of time with a particular space relative to their body.  The third most common was music-color type (41%), which is fairly straightforward. The majority experienced more than one type (clearly, given the percentages).

Here is a graph showing the percentage of the cohort who reported particular synesthetic experiences, grouped according to the category of inducer:

[image]

Note that the most common type mentioned above, grapheme-color, includes all three of the first categories - "digits," "letters," and  "words" on this graph. Although only the inducers are listed here, the most common associated perceptions were indeed color (97%), followed by spatial configurations (62%). In most cases the color was static (73%) but in some people it moved in a specific direction (16%).

---

1. Niccolai V1, Jennes J, Stoerig P, Van Leeuwen TM. *Modality and variability of synesthetic experience.* Am J Psychol. 2012 Spring;125(1):81-94.
2. Simner J1, Mulvenna C, Sagiv N, Tsakanikos E, Witherby SA, Fraser C, Scott K, Ward J. *Synaesthesia: the prevalence of atypical cross-modal experiences.* Perception. 2006;35(8):1024-33.